# How to remove elements from a list if they contain multiple matching properties?

Tags: java, arrays, filter, duplicates, java-stream

I have a List of elements and I need to filter the list so it doesn't contain any duplicate elements, but only if multiple properties are matching. In this example, I have a person class with a firstName, lastName, and age. I've created some persons in a People list and want to remove any duplicate persons with a matching first and last name (ignoring age). Doesn't matter which specific matching person is left, I just am trying to get a resulting array with only one of the unique first and last names.

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Doe", 25);
        Person p2 = new Person("Mike", "Doe", 54);
        Person p3 = new Person("John", "Doe", 61);
        Person p4 = new Person("Barry", "Adams", 61);
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);
        people.add(p4);  

        people.stream().filter(v -> ????????????)
        System.out.println(people);
    }
}


public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
[Mike Doe, John Doe, Barry Adams]
```

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for similar questions? What have you found?  How did they fail to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of `[firstName, lastName]` as key, and group the results using `toMap()` with a merge function:

```
Collection<Person> uniques = people.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                p -> Arrays.asList(p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName()),
                p -> p, (p1, p2) -> p1))
        .values();
```

If you're just looking for the actual full name strings, it's even simpler:

```
Set<String> names = people.stream()
        .map(Person::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your *Person* class doesn't have an *age* field.

If *streams* aren't a requirement, you can use a *for-loop* on the list, and a *[ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)* to check and remove the values.

```java
Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Doe");
Person p2 = new Person("Mike", "Doe");
Person p3 = new Person("John", "Doe");
Person p4 = new Person("Barry", "Adams");
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(p1);
people.add(p2);
people.add(p3);
people.add(p4);

String firstName, lastName;
Person person;
ListIterator<Person> iterator;
for (int index = 0; index < people.size(); index++) {
    firstName = people.get(index).firstName;
    lastName = people.get(index).lastName;
    iterator = people.listIterator(index + 1);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        person = iterator.next();
        if (firstName.equals(person.firstName) && lastName.equals(person.lastName))
            iterator.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(people);
```

Output

```
[Mike Doe, John Doe, Barry Adams]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code like this isn't working.

The constructor of `class Person` needs two arguments (firstName, lastName), but when you instantiate a Person you provide three arguments (firstName, lastName and most likely age).

The answer depends on whats correct.

If there is no age argument (or any other member variable that make the whole person unique) then there is no way to filter a specific instance of `Person`.

In this case you need to extend the class `Person` with a member variable that is unique (such as id).

Then your code might look like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Doe");
        Person p2 = new Person("Mike", "Doe");
        Person p3 = new Person("John", "Doe");
        Person p4 = new Person("Barry", "Adams");
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);
        people.add(p4);  

        people.stream().filter(person -> person.equals(p2))
        System.out.println(people);
    }
}
```

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private UUID uuid;
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public bool equals(Person person) {
        return this.getUUID().equals(person.getUUID());
    }
 
    public String getUUID() {
        return this.uuid.toString();
    }

}
```

If you have a further member variable like the age, just filter by that value:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Mike", "Doe", 25);
        Person p2 = new Person("Mike", "Doe", 54);
        Person p3 = new Person("John", "Doe", 61);
        Person p4 = new Person("Barry", "Adams", 61);
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);
        people.add(p4);  

        people.stream().filter(person -> person.compareFirstName("Mike") && person.compareLastName("Doe") && person.compareAge(54))
        System.out.println(people);
    }
}
```

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + ": " + age;
    }

    public boolean compareFirstName(String firstName) {
        return this.firstName.equals(firstName);
    }

    public boolean compareLastName(String lastName) {
        return this.lastName.equals(lastName);
    }

    public boolean compareAge(int age) {
        return this.age == age;
    }

}
```